# Chaining asynchronous methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have something like below. So each value depends on the other one:

```
var valueX = methodX();
var valueY = methodDependingOnX(valueX);
var valueZ = methodDependingOnY(valueY);
// More code here
```

I wonder how to deal with it in an async way which keeps the UI responsive?
This is the real code I have:

```
Parser parser = new Parser();
LinqQueryManager linq = new LinqQueryManager();
ExcelManager manager = new ExcelManager();

//this return the path of the xml file created
string xmlPreviousCreated = Parser.GenerateXMLDBAsync(file1.FilePath, xmlFile1.FilePath, "Previous");

//now previous depends on the xml file created
List<ExcelBlock> previous = linq.GetListofBlocks(xmlPreviousCreated, xmlFile1.FilePath);

//the same with the next two variables
string xmlCurrentCreated = parser.GenerateXMLDBAsync(file2.FilePath, xmlFile2.FilePath, "Current");

List<ExcelBlock> current = linq.GetListofBlocks(xmlCurrentCreated, xmlFile2.FilePath);
//finally this depends on the previous vars
manager.CreateExcelFile(previous, current);
```

I'm trying to call the methods in some way that the UI keeps responsive. Because the method who create the xml file takes a while. I have two methods that create xml files and other two that query them. What I want is to do this in a efficient way but I'm not sure if I can use parallel or asyn programming. It's the first time dealing with it

Comment: How does the method signature of each method looks like ?

Comment: If you google for `C# async` you'll find that C# already provides asynchronous calls and awaiting them with Tasks and `async/await`. Have you looked into anything?

Comment: Hey guys thanks for so fast response. The problem is that I'm not sure about what to use: Parallel or asynchronous programming. Brief description: I 'm generating two xml files and afer the creation of these files I am querying them. The code I posted is just the structure I have. Any Ideas?

Comment: @LinoBallagas So what problems are you having with that code?  In what way is it not working as desired?

Comment: I'm trying to call the methods in some way that the UI keeps responsive. Because the method who create the xml file takes a while. I have two methods that create xml files and other two that query them. What I want is to do this in a efficient way but I'm not sure if I can use parallel or asyn programming. It's the first time dealing with it.

Comment: @LinoBallagas are you edits accurate? you have some awaits before. What is the actual code?

Comment: @LinoBallagas So what problems are you having with that code? In what way is it not working as desired?  You've told us what your code is doing, but not what problems you have with what your code is doing, or how it's not working as intended.

Comment: The code in my last edit is what I have now. I want to transform it to use asyn or parallel programming.

Comment: @LinoBallagas you have method with postfix `Async` that do not return a `Task`?

Comment: Yes NKosi that's correct. I'm sorry if it looks weird but this is my first incursion with this.

Comment: @LinoBallagas is `Parser` 3rd party code or code you control? If you control the code then read up on how to convert you code to use Tasks. The problem here is that you are not explaining yourself clearly, which is causing unnecessary back and forth to get to the root of your problem/issue.

Comment: The code is all write on my own. I'm going to try suggestions. Thanks you all guys.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this depending on the signature of the methods involved.

If each one of those method are already async/await ready ie return `Task`, it is a simple as

```
var valueX = await methodX();
var valueY = await methodDependingOnX(valueX);
var valueZ = await methodDependingOnY(valueY);
// More code here
```

Assuming the method signatures is something like

```
public Task<string> methodX();
```

If not you would also consider wrapping the said calls.

```
var result = await Task.Run(() => {
    var valueX = methodX();
    var valueY = methodDependingOnX(valueX);
    var valueZ = methodDependingOnY(valueY);
    return valueZ;
});
// More code here
```

Comment: Thanks Nkosi!!. I'm sorry I should post the original code since the beginning. I edited the post with my code and a brief description about what I want to do. Any ideas?

Comment: @LinoBallagas then you are going to have to clarify exactly what is the problem with the code you posted.

Comment: I put some comments on the code to clarify a little bit what I want